# Join a table based on a value in an hstore result

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Noobie join question.

I am trying to retrieve the value that is in an hstore such as location_id.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS where locations -> '12345679' = 'true';
```

I then want to take the results and retrieve the locations based on the ID results 
 in these hstores and have it in the same row.

```
users: {
    location: {
        location_id: '12345679',
        location_name: 'USA';
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Table structure

Users
user_id: uuid,
locations: hstore 'location_id' -> true

Locations
location_id: uuid

Comment: Can you provide the table structure and example data for it?

Comment: users
user_id: uuid
locations: hstore locaiton_ids

locations
location_id: uuid